# AngularJS: How to untick a checkbox automatically when the element related is expired from a date set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with several items inside. Those items have an active column with a checkbox which indicates if that item is active. 
The user can manually untick to disable the items but the items have also an expiration date. What I want to achieve is that when the expiration of an item arrive the box has to untick automatically and the status has to be changed from enable to disable. So the user see is not anymore enable.

I'm sharing with you what I have as an example:

This is the controller:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.item.length; i++) {
                var a = new Date($scope.item[i].to)
                var b = new Date()
                if ($scope.item[i].to != null && (a < b)) {
                    $scope.item[i].expired = true
                }

            }
$scope.changeStatus = function(item) {
        item.isDisabled = !item.isDisabled;
        $scope.save(item);
    };

    $scope.save = function(item) {
        ItemResource.update(item, function success() {
            $scope.loadingAction = false
            toaster.pop({ type: 'success', body: $translate.instant('notifications', { name: item.name }) })
        }, function error() {})
    }
```

View:

```
<td class="td-with-button center valign-top">
                    <span class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="changeStatus(item)">
                        <i class="icon--big fa fa-check-circle-o" ng-class="{'fa-check-circle-o' : !item.isDisabled, 'fa-circle-o' : item.isDisabled}"></i>
                    </span>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to continually check if something is expired would probably be creating a background factory. You could check over and over, or you could create a timeout when the page loads that runs a function to do whatever you'd like (in this case, send a broadcast back to the controller to uncheck that box).

```
angular.module('expirationCheck', []).factory('expirationCheck', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

var service = {}
var expDate = null;

service.setexpDate = function(date) {
    expDate = date;

    var expiration = new Date(expDate);
    var timeout = expiration.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
    setTimeout (function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("Uncheck box");
    }, timeout);
}    

return service;
}]);
```

In your controller, you would inject the facotry and call the "setExpDate" to start the timer. Then you set a watch for "Uncheck box" and do the unchecking there.